# how to combine this linq query to a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, linq-to-entities

i have two tables course which has CourseID and Name, and Section which has SectionID, CourseID, price, time. i  have the following code and i dont know how to use desiplaymember and displayvalue of a combobox.
thanks in advance

```
var fillcmb=(from crs in re.Sections
             from r in re.Courses
                where crs.CourseID == r.CourseID
                select r.Name.ToString()).ToList();

        coursecmb.DataSource = fillcmb;
        coursecmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
        coursecmb.ValueMember = "CourseID";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting appropriate properties from your LINQ query:

```
var fillcmb=(from crs in re.Sections
             from r in re.Courses
                where crs.CourseID == r.CourseID
                select new { Name = r.Name.ToString(), CourseID = crs.CourseID})
            .ToList();
```

Comment: brother Farhad when i debug your code it shows me : Exception:Thrown: "Cannot bind to the new display member." (System.ArgumentException)
A System.ArgumentException was thrown: "Cannot bind to the new display member."
Time: 08/3/2015 11:58:43 AM
Thread:<No Name>[3800]

Comment: @r.hamd Are you sure you have complelety changed your query?

Comment: yes here what i debug :                                                                        var fillcmb = (from crs in re.Sections
                     from r in re.Courses
                     where crs.CourseID == r.CourseID
                     select new { Name = r.Name.ToString(), CourseID = crs.CourseID }).ToList();
            coursecmb.DataSource = fillcmb;
            coursecmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
            coursecmb.ValueMember = "CourseID";

Comment: when the pointer of debugging goes to  (coursecmb.DataSource = fillcmb) the above mentioned exception comes up

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed `DisplayMember` somewhere else in your code? For example from design view?

Comment: brother i am using dotnetbar componets and the default value of DisplayMember is written(Text) and for the valuemember is empty

Comment: dear brother Kak Farhad may i know where are you from, i would like to thank you for your help i removed the default assigned value which was (Text) from the DesplayMember of the combox. and hopefully i worked i will assign your answer as yes again thanks from kurdistan to where you live